# Socrata Open Data API Resource ID Generation

Tags: socrata, soda

I am new to Socrata Open Data. I am trying to access a dataset from NYC DOB Violations. I registered myself and have an App Token and I know the endpoint.

```
public ResourceMetadata GetMetadata(string resourceId)
    {
        if (FourByFour.IsNotValid(resourceId))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("resourceId", "The provided resourceId is not a valid Socrata (4x4) resource identifier.");

        var uri = SodaUri.ForMetadata(Host, resourceId);

        var metadata = read<ResourceMetadata>(uri);
        metadata.Client = this;

        return metadata;
    }
```

How do I get the resource ID? I have a dataset I am interested in and I would like to Programmatically download the file every month?
I downloaded the .Net Library and SDK but am not able to figure out a way to do that . 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the resource identifier from the API docs for that dataset:

https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofnewyork.us/dvnq-fhaa

The identifier is the eight alphanumeric questions separated into two groups of four after `/resource/`. For that dataset, it would be `dvnq-fhaa`.

Good luck!

Comment: Also, FYI, since I realized this can be confusing even if you land on the API docs for a dataset, I added the identifier explicitly in the sidebar of the documentation. Hopefully that's clearer now!

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way if we can download the entire dataset through the API?

Comment: You can either use a `$limit` greater than the number of records in the dataset, or you can use the "Export" function in the dataset page to just grab a CSV.